# Return object with highest value from multiple arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I have an array with multiple arrays of objects and Im trying to find the object with the highest value.

```
values = [
[ {_: "NAN", id: 1},
  {_: "NAN", id: 2},
  {_: "NAN", id: 3}
],
[{_: "3.006", id: 4},
 {_: "7.206", id: 5},
 {_: "1.906", id: 6}
],
[{_: "3.226", id: 7},
 {_: "2.222", id: 8}
 {_: "2.224", id: 9}
],
[{_: "0.006", id: 10},
 {_: "0.321", id: 11},
 {_: "0.938", id: 12}
]]
```

i tried to use .map and .find

```
        var a = Math.max(...values.map(e => e._))
        const highestPoint = values.find(values => values._ === a)
```

But its only bringing back NAN as highest point `const highestPoint = {_: "NAN", id: 1}`, like its only looking through the first array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could flat the arrays and take a filter with [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) and reduce the array.

```js
var values = [[{ _: "NAN", id: 1 }, { _: "NAN", id: 2 }, { _: "NAN", id: 3 }], [{ _: "3.006", id: 4 }, { _: "7.206", id: 5 }, { _: "1.906", id: 6 } ], [{ _: "3.226", id: 7 }, { _: "2.222", id: 8 }, { _: "2.224", id: 9 }], [{ _: "0.006", id: 10 }, { _: "0.321", id: 11 }, { _: "0.938", id: 12 }]],
    highest = values
        .flat()
        .filter(({ _ }) => isFinite(_))
        .reduce((a, b) => +a._ > +b._ ? a : b);

console.log(highest);
```

Comment: Of course, `Array.flat()` is all that is needed. I was using `Array.flatMap()`!

Comment: I would argue that using isFinite would exclude correct maximum when you have +Infinity in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Array.flatMap()` and `Array.map()` to put all the objects into one array, `Array.filter()` to remove the objects with "NAN", then `Array.reduce` to find the highest number:

```js
let vals=[[{_:"NAN",id:1},{_:"NAN",id:2},{_:"NAN",id:3}],[{_:"3.006",id:4},{_:"7.206",id:5},{_:"1.906",id:6}],[{_:"3.226",id:7},{_:"2.222",id:8},{_:"2.224",id:9}],[{_:"0.006",id:10},{_:"0.321",id:11},{_:"0.938",id:12}]];

let res = vals.flatMap(arr => {
    return arr.map(obj => obj)
}).filter(obj => obj._ != "NAN").reduce((prv,cur) => prv._ > cur._ ? prv : cur)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

When any of the arguments to `Math.max` is not a number the result will be `NaN`.

You have an array of arrays, so when mapping you get arrays as the argument to `Math.max` so you need to filter the data and then pass it to max.

Something like this should work

`values.flat().filter(item => !isNaN(Number(item._)))`

Then you can pass this to `max` and will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and fast enough:**

```
const max = (arr = []) => {
  return arr.reduce(
    (m, i) => {
      i.forEach((x) => {
        if (x._ !== 'NAN' && m._ < x._) {
          m = x;
        }
      });
      return m;
    },
    { _: -Infinity }
  );
};
```

```js
const max = (arr = []) => {
  return arr.reduce(
    (m, i) => {
      i.forEach((x) => {
        if (x._ !== 'NAN' && m._ < x._) {
          m = x;
        }
      });
      return m;
    },
    { _: -Infinity }
  );
};
const data = [
  [
    { _: "NAN", id: 1 },
    { _: "NAN", id: 2 },
    { _: "NAN", id: 3 },
  ],
  [
    { _: "3.006", id: 4 },
    { _: "7.206", id: 5 },
    { _: "1.906", id: 6 },
  ],
  [
    { _: "3.226", id: 7 },
    { _: "2.222", id: 8 },
    { _: "2.224", id: 9 },
  ],
  [
    { _: "0.006", id: 10 },
    { _: "0.321", id: 11 },
    { _: "0.938", id: 12 },
  ],
];
console.log(max(data));
```